# "Performance" power mode not available on one of my laptops

Tags: power-management

In one of my laptops, I don't have the option to select "performance" power mode, since it doesn't show up on the options available (just balanced and power saver).

Now, I understand that this happens with some hardware and I could accept that my machine (that one in particular I mean) is just to old for that, but when I tried a different Ubuntu-based distribution, it does show up as an option.

How can I forcefully enable the performance option in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS? Since that is the distribution that I intend to use with that laptop, and not the derivative. Cheers.

EDIT 1: The laptop with the issue is a HP 14 R017 from around 2015. It has a Pentium n3540, 8gb of ram and a mechanical hard drive.
I have been using this laptop with Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS for a year, without issues of any kind. I decided to try Regolith Desktop (Ubuntu based) since the tiling window manager will provide a bit of a performance increase; and it did. On Regolith, Performance was available as an option on the power settings. Keep in mind that Regolith uses pieces of Gnome, pieces of i3, and some other components. But the point remains the same, performance was available.

I know that performance mode can be enabled, even if it is by force on unsupported hardware. The question is, how to do it on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (the one with Gnome), without having to install a different distribution.

Comment: I have the same issue on one of my laptops HP Omen 15-5000na Intel Core i7-4710HQ @ 2.50Ghz x 8 and I don't know why. But you have not given any details about your laptop so I suggest you update your question with more info. Maybe there is a pattern to these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I want to thanks @Karel, since it was him who gave me the solution on another post.

What I did to "enable" the "performance" mode as an option was to manually upgrade the package power-profiles-daemon from version 0.10 (LTS) to 0.12 (Kinetic), without breaking the system and sticking for every other package as the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS intended to be.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/power-profiles-daemon/power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./power-profiles-daemon_0.12-1_amd64.deb
reboot
```

Open settings and select on the power section the now available "performance" option that previously wasn't there.